# Accessing XML data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

Say I have this XML, which repeats itself:

```
<sample>
    <org.postgis.Point>
     <dimension>2</dimension>
     <haveMeasure>false</haveMeasure>
     <type>1</type>
     <srid>4326</srid>
     <x>-73.43975830078125</x>
     <y>42.0513801574707</y>
     <z>0.0</z>
     <m>0.0</m>
    </org.postgis.Point>
<sample>
```

And am using jQuery to try to get the x and y coordinates out of it. How do I do that?

```
   $(xml).find('sample').each(function(){
      $(this).find('org.postgis.Point').each(function(){
         var x = $(this).find('x').text();
```

Is this the right idea? Is there a less verbose way to get inside nested tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to escape the `.`s, because in CSS selectors, they represent classes. Next, you can drop a level of `each`es by using the descendant combinator, :

```
$(xml).find('sample org\\.postgis\\.Point').each(function() {
     var x = $(this).find('x').text();
```

And of course, if there's only one `org.postgis.Point`:

```
var x = $(xml).find('sample org\\.postgis\\.Point x').text();
```